# Recursive function for max element in a list

Tags: python, recursion

I am working on an exercise which asks me to write a recursive function with min() to return the max item in a list.

```
def max_rec(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    minimum_val = min(L[0], L[-1])
    return max_rec(L.remove(minimum_val))

max_rec([1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0])
```

When I call on the function, I get an error saying that an object of type 'Nonetype' has no len(). For the list above, the code successfully removes the 0. The error occurs once it begins working on the modified list without the 0.

What is the reasoning for this error?

Thanks

Comment: python builtins are consequently designed the way that mutator functions do not return anything. `remove` mutates the list and  returns nothing (None).

Comment: `return max_rec(L.remove(minimum_val))` The `.remove()` method modifies the list in place; it does not return anything, and therefore it returns `None` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `remove()` modifies the list directly, similar to `append()` and `pop()`. It returns `None`, so you are modifying the original list and passing `None` when recursively calling `max_rec()`. The solution is to remove `minimum_val` on a separate line and then pass `L`.

```
def max_rec(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    minimum_val = min(L[0], L[-1])
    L.remove(minimum_val)
    return max_rec(L)

print(max_rec([1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0]))
```

Hope this answers your question.